# Tengo problemas con una cadena de inserts con arrays PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

Busco un poco de sabiduría en `PHP`, tengo un formulario en donde el usuario puede "crear" un curso, estos datos los recibe un `PHP` para enviarlo a la `BD`, el detalle esta en que tengo 4 campos que son `arrays`:

- Fechas_curso
- Tipo_jornadas
- Horarios_curso
- Relatores_curso

Estos datos los envío a una `BD` con las siguientes tablas:

Curso:

- id_curso
- nombre_curso
- horas_curso
- id_ambito
- codigo_sigper
- vacantes
- ubicación
- descripcion
- id_relator
- disponible

Jornadas_curso:

- id_curso
- fechas_curso
- horario_curso
- tipo_jornada

```html
// Query para obtener ultimo ID de curso
        $con=mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'capacitaciones');
        $obtener_ultimo_id = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT cursos.id_curso FROM `capacitaciones`.`cursos` order by cursos.id_curso desc limit 1");
         while ($row = $obtener_ultimo_id->fetch_assoc()) {
          echo "Ultima ID de cursos: ", $row['id_curso']."<br>";
          $id_padre = $row['id_curso']+1;
        }

         // Query para obtener el nombre del curso
         $curso_nom = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT `nombre_curso` FROM `cursos` WHERE `nombre_curso` = '$nombre_curso'"); 
         echo "Nombre del curso: ";
         echo $nombre_curso;
         print_r($curso_nom);
         echo "<br>", "Valor ID PADRE: ", " ", $id_padre, "<br>";

         // For para insertar datos del curso por fila
         $cadena_curso = "INSERT INTO `capacitaciones`.`cursos` (`nombre_curso`, `horas_curso`, `id_ambito`, `codigo_sigper`, `vacantes`, `ubicacion`, `descripcion`, `id_relator`, `disponible`) VALUES  ";

         $cadena_jornada = "INSERT INTO `capacitaciones`.`jornadas_cursos` (`id_curso`, `fechas_curso`, `horario_curso`, `tipo_jornada`) VALUES ";

         for ($i = 0; $i <count($fechas_curso); $i++){
            echo $p_name[$i], " <br> ";
            echo $tipo_jornada, " <br> ";

            $cadena_curso = "('".$nombre_curso."', '".$horas_curso."', '".$id_ambito."', '".$codigo_sigper."', '".$vacantes."', '".$ubicacion."', '".$descripcion."', '".$p_name[$i]."', 'si'),";

           // printf ("Nuevo registro con el id %d.\n", $cadena_curso->insert_id);

            $cadena_jornada = "('".$id_padre."', '".$fechas_curso[$i]."', '".$horario_curso[$i]."', '".$tipo_jornada[$i]."'),";
           } 
         
          $cadena_curso_final = substr($cadena_curso, 0, -1);
          $cadena_curso_final.=";";


          $cadena_jornada_final = substr($cadena_jornada, 0, -1);
          $cadena_jornada_final.=";";

          print_r($cadena_jornada_final);

        printf ("Resultado cadena curso \n", $cadena_curso_final, "<br>");

          if(mysqli_query($con, $cadena_curso_final)):
            echo json_encode(array('error' => false));
          else:
              echo json_encode(array('error' => true));
          endif;
          

          if(mysqli_query($con, $cadena_jornada_final)):
            echo json_encode(array('error' => false));
          else:
              echo json_encode(array('error' => true));
          endif;
```

y tengo el `PHP` de la foto para guardar los datos, sin embargo, no me los guarda en la `BD` y solo me tira al `echo json_encode(array('error' => true));`

¿En donde podría estar el error? Las cadenas, la consulta...

De antemano, muchas gracias por cualquier ayuda

Comment: Antes de nada, comprueba que la conexión es correcta `if(!$con){echo "Error," . PHP_EOL;}`

Comment: Deberías mostrarnos `$cadena_curso_final` y `$cadena_jornada_final`, así como enviar un error diferente según el punto donde se produzca. Ademas  de `error = true` podrías añadirle un código o el texto de la consulta que lo generó.

Comment: Mikel ferreiro, agregue el codigo:

   if(!$con){echo "Error con conexión de base de datos," . PHP_EOL;
           }else{
              echo "Exito";
           }

Y la conexión se dio sin problemas

Comment: Fly, no te entiendo bien, por ejemplo $cadena_curso_final seria finalmente el resultado de $cadena_curso + ";" , sobre el error, tu te refieres a algo asi?:

echo json_encode(array('error $cadena_curso_final' => true));

Comment: Cambia los mensajes de error, poniendo esto: **`echo json_encode(array('error' => true, 'msg'=>mysqli_error($con)));`**  ahí tendrás en `msg` el mensaje de error.

Comment: A. Cedano, muchas gracias, lo probe y me da error de null:

{"error":true,"msg":null}

Comment: A mi me da la impresión de que tu conexión es nula... Haz un `var_dump($con);` sólo para prueba ehhh, que eso saca hasta la constraseña por pantalla. Y dinos si realmente te muestra un objeto conexión. Luego quitas el `var_dump`, por supuesto. O bien haz un `var_dump($obtener_ultimo_id);`   a ver qué pasa.

Comment: A. Cedano, le estoy haciendo unos cambios al codigo y lo publico, solo por curiosidad, hay manera directa de comunicarse a traves de stackoverflow? Lo digo porq estoy saliendo a terreno en este momento, saludos

Comment: A. Cedano, hice los cambios a mi codigo, sobre el var_dump lo hice y me regresa esto:

Comment: object(mysqli)#2 (17) { ["affected_rows"]=> int(0) ["client_info"]=> string(50) "mysqlnd 5.0.5-dev - 081106 - $Revision: 1.3.2.27 $" ["client_version"]=> int(50005) ["connect_errno"]=> int(0) ["connect_error"]=> string(0) "" ["errno"]=> int(0) ["error"]=> string(0) "" ...

Comment: Yo me refería a: `echo json_encode(array('error' => true,'cod'=>1,'sql'=>$cadena_curso_final));`  y `echo json_encode(array('error' => true,'cod'=>2,'sql'=>$cadena_jornada_final));`  prefiero ver la consulta y podrás probarla directamente contra la db. Además no me queda claro en que punto te da el error. Edita la pregunta y añade los resultados obtenidos

Comment: Según la documentación: [mysqli_query](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php) : *"Retorna **FALSE** en caso de error. Si una consulta del tipo **SELECT**, **SHOW**, **DESCRIBE** o **EXPLAIN** es exitosa, mysqli_query() retornará un objeto mysqli_result. Para otras consultas exitosas de mysqli_query() retornará **TRUE**."*  Así que es extraño que te devuelva error `null`, estás pasando algo por alto. Edita la  pregunta y añade los resultados obtenidos.